# Google Chrome removes autofill data on Debian

Tags: debian, autocomplete, chrome

Every time I open Google Chrome Beta on Debian, it does not show autofill data; i.e. it does not fill in usernames and passwords automatically though they are visible in Google Passwords. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The following has helped me:

1. Close all instances of Google Chrome (or Beta)
2. Go to `~/.config/google-chrome(-beta)` and open the profile directory you wish to modify (Generally the `Default` directory)
3. Remove the `Login Data` and `Login Data-journal` files.

That should fix the problem.